# Writing to Pandas Column Within for loop in Python

Tags: python, php, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

this is for sure a lack of knowledge issue as I am generally new to scraping. What I am trying to accomplish with this code is to scrape all of the data on the webpage which I am accomplishing. The issue is before the loops continues I want pandas to write the current position_text variable to the ["Positions"] column. I confirmed with the print statement it is pulling exactly what I am looking to write to the new ["Position"] column, but it is only writing the last instance to ["Position"] which is "C"

Link: https://www.fantasypros.com/daily-fantasy/nba/fanduel-defense-vs-position.php

```
df_results = pd.DataFrame()
​
follow_loop=list(range(1,7))
for i in follow_loop:
    xpath = '//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li['
    xpath += str(i)
    xpath += "]"
    driver.find_element(By. XPATH,(xpath)).click()
    
    sleep (2)
   
        
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1,1200)")
  
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1,-1200)")
    
        
    
​
    html=driver.page_source
​
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
​
    stats_table=soup.find(id="data-table")
    
    position='//*[@id="main-container"]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[1]/ul/li['
    position += str(i)
    position += "]"
    position_text =  driver.find_element(By. XPATH,(position)).text
    
    df_results = df_results.append(pd.read_html(str(stats_table)))
    df_results["Position"] = position_text
    print(position_text)
    sleep (2)
    
    
ALL
PG
SG
SF
PF
C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of getting the data from all tables, in one big dataframe:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time as t
import pandas as pd 

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
big_df = pd.DataFrame()
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = "https://www.fantasypros.com/daily-fantasy/nba/fanduel-defense-vs-position.php"
driver.get(url)

tables_list = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//ul[@class="pills pos-filter pull-left"]/li')))

for x in tables_list:
    x.click()
    print('selected', x.text)
    t.sleep(2)
    table = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//table[@id="data-table"]')))
    df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    df['Category'] = x.text.strip()
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    print('done, moving to next table')
print(big_df)
big_df.to_csv('fanduel.csv')
```

This will save the data to a csv file, and also display it in terminal:

```
Team    PTS REB AST 3PM STL BLK TO  FD PTS  Category
0   HOUHouston Rockets  23.54   9.10    5.10    2.54    1.88    1.15    2.65    48.55   ALL
1   OKCOklahoma City Thunder    22.22   9.61    5.19    2.70    1.67    1.18    2.52    47.57   ALL
2   PORPortland Trail Blazers   22.96   8.92    5.31    2.74    1.63    0.99    2.65    46.84   ALL
3   SACSacramento Kings 23.00   9.10    5.03    2.58    1.61    0.95    2.50    46.65   ALL
4   ORLOrlando Magic    22.35   9.39    4.94    2.62    1.57    1.04    2.50    46.36   ALL
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
175 DENDenver Nuggets   22.96   12.91   3.68    0.96    1.21    1.76    2.62    50.26   C
176 PHIPhiladelphia 76ers   21.95   13.35   3.01    1.15    1.14    1.94    2.07    49.66   C
177 BOSBoston Celtics   19.52   14.46   3.58    0.61    1.40    1.82    2.80    49.10   C
178 NYKNew York Knicks  19.31   14.48   3.02    1.07    1.02    1.98    2.26    47.96   C
179 MIAMiami Heat   19.00   14.44   2.95    0.64    1.24    1.55    2.71    46.41   C
```

Comment: You are welcome @mmoore0323. Stackoverflow policy is **one question per post**, so if you have further questions, you are welcome to ask them separately. I have not seen that ad you mention, but you can always add an adblocking extension when initializing the driver. Game recency - yes, it's doable with nested loops.